# Select within another select using the LIKE operator

Tags: database, postgresql

**GOAL**

I need to make a select inside another select using the LIKE operator converting the value of the other select to LOWER, but it's returning me error

**QUERY**

```
 select *
 from tbl_client
 where "NODE" like ('%' select lower ("HOST")
                        from ahc_msystems
                        where "NODE" = 'UTE: pdo-sc03zdbdam030507: NT' '%')
```

**OUTPUT**

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" Line: 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=055e7332ab2550bc7925bf9b9040332c)

The right side of your `LIKE` needs to be

```
LIKE '%' || (SELECT ...) || '%'
```

First you need to `SELECT` your string data and after that concatenate it with wildcards using `||` operator

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround the subquery with parentheses and concatenate the strings:

```
select *
from tbl_client
where "NODE" like '%' || (select lower("HOST")
                          from ahc_msystems
                          where "NODE" = 'UTE: pdo-sc03zdbdam030507: NT')
                      || '%';
```

This will only work if the subquery returns a single value.

Comment: How do we use this if the subquery returns multiple rows? Array functions?

Comment: @analytical_prat That would cause an error. You could use `array_agg()` and compare with `LIKE ANY`.